# Calling a test class A's method from a test class B's method

Tags: php, phpunit

I am using phpunit to unit test. In some test classes, I need to perform same tests that is already implemented in another test class.

So is it possible to call another test class's test method?

Comment: May u should extract the function to a helper-class?

Answer (score 0):

You can call a test method of another class.  You can create an instance of the test class in the test and then call the method.

However, just because you can do something doesn't mean you should do something.

The use case that you are describing sounds like you have duplicated functionality.  You should reconsider your design so that you do not need to do what you are describing.  Your tests should be fairly small functions that are easy to follow.  If you are reaching out to other test classes, your tests can become difficult to maintain, brittle, and hard to understand.

Comment: Yes, there is duplication of tests. Scenario is that to perform certain operation I call a method of a class A which in turn delegates the work to class B's method and on receipt of response it may modify the result and pass back to me. That is why test methods for both of these methods may be the same and I need to call a test method from another class.

Comment: You don't need to duplicate the tests.  Look into Mock objects and create a mock of class B's method for testing class A rather than trying to call another test.  http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#test-doubles.mock-objects